# Низкоуровневый сетевой протокол на ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, qt, c++

Как написать низкоуровневый сетевой протокол на ассемблере? Хочу реализовать замену tcp/ip с использованием DHT, а в качестве адресного пространства взять sha кэш MAC адреса и использовать для защиты канала openssl библиотеку.

*Обновление*

Почему ассемблер? Он мне знаком. Просто я не знаю как реализовать на c++, так как там придётся использовать старые готовые решения (tcpserver, winsocket). Хочу принципиально отдельно от tcp/ip. Я делаю децентрализованный протокол который будет у пользователей и как сервер и как клиент (участие самого отдельного сервера не требуется и будет востребовано только отдельными сервисами).

"Шифрование идет повыше транспортного уровня, разве нет?" - Правильно, я буду делать несколько уровней.

Я думаю делать на платформу linux и windows.

*Обновление 2*

Попробую начать с канального уровня. Есть примеры как должен выглядеть код что бы отойти от ip? С сетевыми приложениями я обычно использовал ThreadPool, TCPSocket

*Обновление 3*

Я не понимаю как на си отойти от ip, если под windows там  придётся использовать wsastartup, то есть socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); Что вместо AF_INET?

В QT вообще не представляю как вместо ip использовать другой протокол. send/recv это только отсылка пакетов. Обьясните, пожалуйста.

*Обновление 4*

Как написать низкоуровневый сетевой протокол? Хочу реализовать замену tcp/ip с использованием DHT, а в качестве адресного пространства взять sha кэш MAC адреса и использовать для защиты канала openssl библиотеку. Каждый компьютер одновременно и сервер и клиент. Я думаю делать на платформу linux и windows.

Да я действительно собираюсь написать альтернативу ip, так как сейчас государство очень жёстко отфильтровывает ресурсы интернета. I2P работает только через интернет и не отходит от использования ip. Я планирую сделать децентролизованную самоорганизованную сеть которая будет использовать адресное пространство в виде sha(потому что опасно в открытом виде транслировать физ. адрес) MAC-адреса(так как MAC адрес уникален).
Пока что в пределах локальной сети, а потом подумаю о расширениях.

На счёт udp там есть проблема от не смотрит состояние придётся делать надстройку что бы каждый пакет проверялся на контрольную сумму. С потоковой трансляцией видео и аудио это не проблема, а вот бинарный файл, архив или документ это серьёзная проблема.

Comment: А Вам принципиально на ассемблере нужно? может начнете с классического С/С++?

Потом нужно решить, насколько низко хотите опуститься. Я предлагаю использовать обычный udp и поверх него делать свой протокол. И делать протокол программного уровня или опуститься ниже. Паралельно узнайте о [OSI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI).

Потом, нужно будет определиться с операционными системами, а дальше уже будет по мелочи.

Comment: Шифрование идет повыше транспортного уровня, разве нет?

Comment: tcpserver/winsock - это уже не просто готовые решения. Но они думаю, они не нужны.

С уровнем OSI уже определились? Если Вам нужны свои адреса, то это нужно на канальный уровень опускаться, но думаю, что это будет сложновато. Либо сетевой (здесь живет IP). Но и здесь похоже, что нужно будет и роутер свой делать (софт), что бы он умел перенаправлять Ваши пакеты. Он то не знает о новой для него адресации

Подымемся выше, на транспортный уровень. Здесь живет TCP/UDP. Выше нет смысла подыматься.

Я рекомендую, посмотреть на udp и сделать на его базе + мультикаст.

Comment: @jack-out, если Вы каким-то образом не ухитритесь обрабатывать прерывания от сетевой карты (т.е. не встроите часть своей программы в ядро), то Вам в любом случае придется использовать сокеты (send/recv) в качестве интерфейса с ядром. 

(На самом нижнем уровне это *raw socket*).

--

А зачем писать на ассемблере при наличии Си -- я не понимаю.

Comment: ThreadPool к сетевым протоколам отношения не имеет.

Еще раз предупреждение - на канальном уровне Вам нужен будет свой роутер, так как обычные роутеры не будут знать, что делать с Вашими пакетами.

Думаю, что начните с того, что скачайте [KolibriOS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/KolibriOS). Он на ассемблере (думаю, для Вас это плюс) и там есть реализация TCP/IP - на ее базе можно написать свою. Потом скачать сорцы ядра линукса и пытаться делать там, но так как будет работающий клиент, то это пойдет легче.

Comment: @jack-out, не знаю, как в винде и QT, а в  Linux для работы с уровнем пакетов

      socket(AF_PACKET, ...);

Вообще, начните с `man 7 socket`, `man 7 raw` и т.п. (см. `SEE ALSO` в manpages).

Потом можете погуглить примеры по запросу  "raw socket".

Вот [тут](http://www.tenouk.com/Module43a.html) IMHO хороший материал по программированию в сети (правда на уровне IP). 

--

А Вы серьезно хотите сделать альтернативу IP? Или в Вашей задаче все обмены ограничиваются одним сегментом локалки?

Comment: @jack-out, вот вспомнил и нашел http://sock-raw.org/papers/sock_raw

Хорошая статья на тему raw sockets:


    What is going to be discussed here will *not* be another tutorial on how to hand-craft one's own packets.
    ...
    We are
going to delve into network stack internals for this reason. It is assumed that
the reader has already some experience with sockets and is willing to look at 
some kernel code since raw sockets implementation is actually OS dependent.

Comment: avp, можно по подробней? И какую литературу можно почитать помимо Олифер.

Comment: @jack-out, а что такое Олифер?

--

В принципе, вопрос о сети альтернативной IP интересный, но не очень жизненный (только если на уровне WI-FI (и т.п.), но опять же потребуется gateway в IP (можно через неконтролируемый спутник, хотя по большому счету это все несерьезно из-за кучи проблем ...)).

--

Смысла менять 48-бит MAC на длинный SHA от него же (?) я никакого не вижу.

Да и как Вы вообще представляете роутинг этих адресов (все же в IP есть упорядоченность, а в Вашей схеме?) в своей альтернативной сети?

--

Насчет поподрбней -- я давно не касался этого уровня -- гляньте kernel sources.

Comment: avp, я шифрую MAC что бы злоумышленники не могли подменить. Большинство провайдеров дают доступ к сети по MAC адресу. SHA скрывает изначальный вид и не обратим. Поиск и взаимодействие будет через DHT, а вот если нужно защищённое прямое подключение, вот тогда только нужна адресация с обменом сертификатов и защитой через openssl.

Comment: `tcpserver` и `winsocket` — это часть программного окружения операционной системы, а потому от языка не зависит.